# How can I define the object type in a returned pipe(map(...)) statement?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I started developing an app in Angular + Ionic Framework.

My problem is that I don't know how to define the type on a returned object to be able to retrieve specific attributes.

I think this is a common problem but I couldn't find the proper results using google.

When I try to return my authentication token from device storage, which looks something like

```
{
   key:'authData',
   value: token
}
```

I am not able to compile as my **value** attribute is not known on the returned *storedData* field.

**error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'unknown'.**

```
return from(Storage.get({ key: 'authData' })).pipe(map(storedData => {
  if (!storedData || !storedData.value) {
    return null;
  }
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData.value)
}
```

So I am looking for some type to define the interface type on the storedData object.
Kind regards!

Comment: Why would you expect `Storage` to return `key:value` pair? Wouldn't this call make more sense `Storage.get('authData')` ?  According to the source code (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-storage/blob/main/lib/src/index.ts#L98), the `get` function takes string as a parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must declare a model in the top of your file

```
interface StoredData {
   key: string;
   value: string;
}
```

And then later in your code:

```
return from(Storage.get({ key: 'authData' })).pipe(map(storedData: StoredData => {
  if (!storedData || !storedData.value) {
    return null;
  }
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData.value)
 }
```

Alternatively you can cheat the linter with:

```
return from(Storage.get({ key: 'authData' })).pipe(map(storedData => {
  if (!storedData || !storedData['value']) {
    return null;
  }
  const parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData['value'])
 }
```

Comment: How is this upvoted and accepted as an answer? If I pulled this off I'd be banned.

Comment: @ItrysohardbutIcryharder The OP vandalized most of their answers.